# Sidekiq sending jobs to test queue instead of developement queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've added specs to cover sidekiq jobs with rspec, but now, when I start a rails server, console, or just sidekiq, I have this warning:

```
WARNING: Sidekiq testing API enabled, but this is not the test environment.  Your jobs will not go to Redis.
```

And jobs are indeed not enqueued.

How can I switch back to the development API?

Comment: how did you integrate sidekiq testing in your application?

Comment: Don't `require 'sidekiq/testing'` anywhere (except rails_helper/spec_helper/test_helper or whatever global test setup file you use)

Comment: I'm getting the same message and I only required it in my `spec_helper`. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Also look for `require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` in the initializer files and/or environment specific files, like `config/environments/development.rb`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might want to check if you've included the gem 'rspec-sidekiq' in the group :development. If it's the case, remove it from there and only call it in the :test group.

Comment: I wish I'd found this 4 hours ago. Thank you!

Comment: You should probably accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Thomas answer above, if you don't find the `rspec-sidekiq` gem in your Gemfile, check if any part of your project code (such as a sidekiq initializer) has code like this:

```
 require 'sidekiq/testing'
 Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem here, and since our development and test envs share the same gems in a dockerized container, we had to solve differently:

1. Turn off auto require for rspec-sidekiq gem in Gemfile

```rb
gem "rspec-sidekiq", ~> "3.1.0", require: false
```

2. Require it only on `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```rb
require "rspec-sidekiq"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when using `sidekiqswarm` and preloading the `test` gems.

Once I made the change, it worked perfect.

Before:

```
worker: SIDEKIQ_COUNT=5 SIDEKIQ_MAXMEM_MB=300 SIDEKIQ_PRELOAD=default,development,test sidekiqswarm -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

After:

````
worker: SIDEKIQ_COUNT=5 SIDEKIQ_MAXMEM_MB=300 SIDEKIQ_PRELOAD=default,development sidekiqswarm -C config/sidekiq.yml```
````